# Groupwise mathematical operation with iteration over sequence that has not the same length

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable that is the addition of carb and the ith element of sequ based on cyl.

I think it might be some group_by operation, but I can't figure out how to iterate through sequ.

```
test_dataset <- mtcars[1:10,]
sequ <- seq(0.5, 0.7, 0.1)
arrange(test_dataset, cyl)
```

The resulting variable would be

```
c(1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 4.6, 4.6, 1.6, 1.6, 4.6, 2.7, 4.7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create the data as a new column, you can do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
test_dataset <- mtcars[1:10,]
sequ <- seq(0.5, 0.7, 0.1)
arrange(test_dataset, cyl) %>% 
  mutate(x = carb + sequ[match(cyl, unique(cyl))])

#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   x
# 1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1.5
# 2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 2.5
# 3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 2.5
# 4  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 4.6
# 5  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 4.6
# 6  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 1.6
# 7  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 1.6
# 8  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 4.6
# 9  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 2.7
# 10 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 4.7
```

So here we use `match` to get the right element of `sequ`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `within`, convert `cyl` `as.factor`, `as.numeric`, and use value to extract from `sequ`.

```
sequ <- seq(0.5, 0.7, 0.1)

within(mtcars[1:10,][order(mtcars[1:10,]$cyl), ], {
  new=carb + sequ[as.numeric(as.factor(cyl))]})
#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new
# Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1.5
# Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 2.5
# Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 2.5
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 4.6
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 4.6
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 1.6
# Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 1.6
# Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 4.6
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 2.7
# Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 4.7
```